# Прокрутить до определенного места

Tags: jquery

Ребят, вот не накоторых сайтах есть FAQ, к примеру:

```
<div id="faq1">
 Ответ 1
</div>
<div id="faq2">
 Ответ 2
</div>
<div id="faq3">
 Ответ 3
</div>
```

И например для ответа 3 есть специальная ссылка - http://site.ru/faq?id=3

Вот как сделать так, чтобы перейдя по этой ссылке, прокрутило именно до Ответа 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Стоит пересмотреть реализацию и сделать более логично.

[Якоря html](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya).

Comment: @Crasher, как все просто оказалось. Благодарю :)

Comment: Хм, классная тема. Спасибо)

Comment: Простите за подобного рода комментарий, но стыдно, что "современное поколение" не знает столь базовых вещей. В "наши времена" начинали с того, что читали самое базовое и простое, потом искали подобные вещи в интернете и лишь потом искали, у кого спросить.

Comment: @Crasher, да я просто не знал, в какую сторону гуглить. Про якоря даже мысли и не было :)

Comment: @Crasher, да нынче все наоборот: от сложного к простому. Поэтому некоторые мелочи, вроде этой, могли остаться незамеченными.

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите "плавную" прокрутку, юзайте JQuery:

```
$('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".bottom").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Не забивайте голову всякими jQuery