# быстрый скролинг сайта в asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

как сделать быстрый скролинг к конкретному блоку текста (нажимая на ссылку на  кнопке), не переходя на другую страницу?

Comment: html якоря чем не угодили?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: HTML якорь `<p id="myanchor">text</p>` ссылка `<a href="#myanchor">go to text</a>`. C# здесь совершенно не при чем.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/243552/373567